# SHGetFolderPath returns path with question marks in it

Tags: c++, winapi, unicode, character-encoding

Our application calls ShGetFolderPath when it runs, to get the My Documents folder. This normally works great. However, for three users - Дмитрий, Jörg and Jörgen (see if you can spot the pattern!) - the call returns some very strange results. For example, for Дмитрий, the call returns:

```
c:\Users\???????\Documents
```

I assume there's some sort of character encoding shenanigan going on here, possibly related to Unicode, but I don't have any experience with that sort of thing. How can I get a useful path to the folder (and other related folders) out of windows, without grovelling through registry keys for the information?

In an email to me, Дмитрий ("Dmitry"), told me his "my documents" folder was actually located here:

```
C:\Users\43D6~1\Documents
```

So I know there's a way to get a "normal" version of the path out of Windows, I just don't know what it is.

Background: Our application is not unicode-aware, and uses standard "char *" strings. How can we get the "normal" path? I'm not opposed to calling the "unicode" version of the function, then converting it to "normal" text, if that's possible. Converting the application entirely to use unicode is not an option here (we don't have the time).

Thanks.

Comment: Standard character, `char`, strings are 8 bit octets by default.  There is not enough room in 8-bits to contain English, Cyrillic and all the other language specific character encodings.  You will have to use some other base for the strings such as *wide* characters or UTC.

Comment: GetShortPathName().  It isn't normal.  Dimitry will have to change his system code page to Windows 1251 to make your program functional.  Ignoring Unicode has a way of resolving itself automatically, users will just stop renewing licenses.

Comment: setlocale can be workaround. I think setlocale(LC_ALL,"Russian") will solve problem for Dmitry. I used it before, it's ugly solution, but fast.

Comment: you simply have to move to Unicode

Comment: "Converting the application entirely to use unicode is not an option here"; how are you going to access files that use characters outside the ANSI codepage?

Comment: We don't! It's sub-optimal, but we don't have the resources to transition to unicode at this time. :(

Comment: @Colen At the very least you are going to need to use UNICODE for any file names that have non-ANSI characters. What's so hard about it anyway?

Comment: You probably don't need to convert the entire program to unicode. Hans's suggestion will get you out of this mess: Use SHGetFolderPathW to get the Unicode name, then use GetShortPathName to get the "short" version of it, which will be something like "C:\Users\43D6~1\Docume~1" and will work fine in the rest of your program. It'll look ugly if you ever display that path to the user but it will work (unless someone disables short paths on the filesystem, but nobody would do that as it breaks a lot of popular software, e.g. MS Office).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Go ahead and get the file path in Unicode. Then call [GetShortPathNameW](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa364989(v=vs.85).aspx) to convert to short pathname components. The output shouldn't contain any characters outside of the ASCII range even though it's a Unicode function. You can then truncate each Unicode character back to 8 bits to create a `char` string.

Answer (score 2):

> I'm not opposed to calling the "unicode" version of the function, then converting it to "normal" text, if that's possible.

If you change your call to `SHGetFolderPath` to `SHGetFolderPathW`, it will provide you with a string of type `LPWSTR`, which is a Unicode string. From there, you can use that string with the various Unicode functions that end with `W` to access the folder or files you need.